# Complex integral using residue theorem if there's no residue

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm supposed to compute the following integral using the residue theorem:

$$\int_{|z+1| = 4} \frac{z}{e^{z}+3}dz$$

To be honest, I don't understand how I should go about it since there are no values of $z$ for which $e^{z}+3=0$. How can I use the residue theorem to solve this integral or how can I solve it without using the theorem?

Comment: Are you sure there are no poles?

Comment: I am not sure but I can't see them

Comment: $e^z=-3 \implies z=\log(-3)$ which is multivalued. There are actually infinitely many poles! See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+e%5Ez+%2B+3+%3D+0+over+complexes

Comment: Check if any logarithm of $-3$ lies inside. Not having any pole is not an issue at all.The integral would be $0$ in that case by Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: As mentioned, there are poles at $\ln 3+(1+2n)i\pi$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. So there are actually two poles $\ln 3\pm i\pi$ in the circle $|z+1|=4$.

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions to $e^z=-3$, in the complex plane, as  is already mentioned above. The complex exponential $e^z$ takes on all the values in the complex plane, except for $0$. Hence, to solve $e^z=-3$, you can say $e^x(e^{iy})=-3$, where I have written $z=x+iy$, with $x$ and $y$ being real numbers.

Hence (using the fact $e^{iy}=\cos y+i\sin y$), we note $e^x\cos y$ is $-3$ and (comparing imaginary parts) we see $e^x \sin y=0$, so $y=\pi$ (or another odd multiple of $\pi$) and thus $-e^x=-3$ and (so $e^x=3$). As $x$ is real, note now it should be fairly easy to solve for $z=x+iy$. Note - for the contour integral, we only care about the roots of $e^z=-3$ (if any) that lie within the circle $|z+1|=4$. Then if $I=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int g(z) \, dz$ where $g=\frac{z}{e^z+3}$, we can find $I$ by residue theorem.